# getting the error while running the Flutter project in ios

Tags: ios, flutter, arm64, avaudiosession, undefined-symbol

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey", referenced from:
-[FlutterCallKitPlugin provider:didActivateAudioSession:] in FlutterCallKitPlugin.o

please need solution for above

Answer (score 0):

Set your project/target build architecture to `x86_64`

[image]